# How high I should install a 52 inch TV on the wall?

Tags: installation

I'm going to hang my TV to the wall and I want to know how much from ground is standard for 52 inch TV?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a standard height for wall mounting flatscreen TVs?](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/5476/is-there-a-standard-height-for-wall-mounting-flatscreen-tvs)

Comment: set yourself in your best position and have a buddy/your wife hold the tv up to the wall and give directions

Comment: @ratchetfreak Moving the TV isn't that easy. Needs two people that I don't have.

Comment: then use a carboard cutout

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, sit on your couch in the ideal viewing position (ie: where your butt imprint is).  The bottom 1/3 of the TV should be at eye level when mounted.  Everyone has an opinion about exact positioning, but this is more or less the general rule of thumb I've found from various sources, and it has always worked well for me.

I find most people mount them too high. No one likes sitting in the front-row at the movie theater, so why do it at home?

Comment: My exact question is `1/2` or `1/3` of TV? It seems there are two theory!

Comment: Get a strong friend to hold it while you sit on the couch or use a table of similar height - it's the only way to really know for sure.

Comment: I went through the exact same ordeal with my 52" set. Steven's advice is spot on. About a third seems like a very comfortable height. Enjoy!!!

Comment: Preference for 1/3 or 1/2 probably depends if you are tall or short (usually look slight down or up at other people's faces)

Answer (score 2):

A small addition to Steven's answer:
Our eyes are designed to focus 8' away from us when looking directly ahead, at our hands when looking down, and not so much looking up.

Comment: This is killer trivia, do you have the citation for this, please.

Comment: It was from reading about computer desk ergonomics.

Answer (score 0):

I would not want to be looking up at the TV. I have found that snacking is uncomfortable when looking anywhere above straight ahead as well as a pain in the neck. I think I would go for the center of the TV at the eyeball height of an average person.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add another preference: I like my TV a little lower; eye level around 2/3 up the screen (more in line with [OSHA's computer monitor height ergonomic recommendations](http://www.osha.gov/SLTC/etools/computerworkstations/components_monitors.html#Angle)).

The only real answer is to try it, preferably with an adjustable-height table or something before it's permanently mounted. I built an entertainment cabinet a year or so ago, and in preparation spent several weeks with my TV on a coffee table with various stacks of books to find a good height. If you just spend 2 seconds looking at a cardboard cutout taped to the wall you're not going to get a good sense of how it feels.